# DetailsView binding correctly but only one field being displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have my DetailsView bound to get data. It correctly returns 4 rows of information but only displays

Skill : Javascript

I assume im missing some sort of loop to implement it to display

```
Skill : Javascript
Skill : C#
Skill : Actionscript 3
Skill : HTML
```

How would I go about implementing it to behave as

```
Skill : Javascript, C#, Actionscript 3, HTML
```

If someone could suggest hwo to implement this I would be greatful.

Comment: My issue was fixed with a combination of both responses and changing my SQL makes things much more simple also. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DetailsView` is used to display the details of a single object. You can't bind a collection.

If you want to show a list, [use a Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx), for example.

```
 <asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
             <table border="1">
          </HeaderTemplate>
          <ItemTemplate>
             <tr>
                <td> Skill: </td>
                <td> <%# Eval("Skill") %> </td>
             </tr>
          </ItemTemplate>
          <FooterTemplate>
             </table>
          </FooterTemplate>
       </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1):

The DetailsView works with records.  If you have 4 strings, you can combine them like:

```
var skills = objects.Select(i => i.Skill);
string skill = String.Join(",", skills);

this.dvw.DataSource = new { Skill = skill };
this.dvw.DataBind();
```

Essentially, you have to concatenate to one record.